# events changed nickname in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Good day.
How can I find out when a user changed their nickname in Discord.js?

I couldn't find the documentation I needed on the Internet.

I looked for information on the Internet

The documentation in discord is not entirely clear to me,
I used Listen to GuildMemberUpdate events but nothing happens.

```
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.GuildMemberUpdate,
    async execute(oldMember, newMember) {
        console.log(oldMember.nickname + "-" + newMember.nickname);
    },
};
```

Comment: What did it print out? Did you check if other listeners work? Also, according to [this documentation](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/User) it should be `oldMember.username` rather than `.nickname`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to pxDav for the tip.
Here's the semi-working code

```js
const { Events } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: Events.GuildMemberUpdate,
    async execute(oldMember, newMember) {
        if (newMember.username != oldMember.username ) {
            const channel = newMember.client.channels.cache.get("1093559282680741969");
            await channel.send(`Change nickname: ${newMember.username}`);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: "*Here's the semi-working code*" Semi-working how? Does this actually answer the question as you posed it above?

Comment: yes, error, I had setNickname set in my code, which triggered this event again, but it is not in the code I provided, so it works completely

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).